# How to indent text on 2nd line in list elements with icon fonts

Tags: css, icon-fonts

I use an icon font for list style elements:

```
.desc.std li:before {
  content: '\e81e';
  font-family: 'icons';
  width: .6em;
}
```

But when the text breaks to 2nd line, I have no text indent.

Can anyone please tell me, how I can get the 2nd and following lines indented?

Comment: Text indent only applies to the first word  of each element (wich only happens in the first line).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possible solution if applicable for your situation:

**CSS**

```
li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}

li:before {
    content: '\e81e';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    font-family: 'icons';
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/6ECpE/)